# Pagination and redirect URL is not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom table for document's users and I want to make pagination for it, I have tried following code but I faced 2 problem.

1. pagination is not working
2. problem in redirect to next page.

Following is code for pagination:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$limit = 2;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  

$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  

$selct_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_singining` LIMIT $start_from, $limit " , OBJECT);
?>

<table align="center" border="1" class="user-listing-table" id="main_listing">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" class="check_all"></th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Status</th>
</tr>

<?php
foreach ($selct_data as  $value) {
    echo '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="check_element" class="check_element"></td><td>'.$value->f_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value->l_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value->email.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value->phone.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value->status.'</td></tr>';
}
?>
</table>

<?php  
$selct_data_ra = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt FROM `wp_singining`
                                                               ", OBJECT);
$total_records = $selct_data_ra[0]->cnt;  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
$pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    $pagLink .= "<li><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
};  
echo $pagLink . "</ul></nav>";  
?>
```

And following code is for redirect to next page I have written in `functions.php` file:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule(){
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'page' );
    add_rewrite_rule('user-listing/(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?','index.php?pagename=user-listing&page=$1','top' );
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

I am confused that what I am doing wrong pagination and redirection not working please help me.

Comment: Explain what is going wrong?

Comment: When i click on next page , page number is showing in url but data is not showing of second page .

Comment: Just after the 2nd line, add the following code: `die('page = ' . $_GET["page"]);`, run and paste here what happens when you have paginated to pages 1, 2, 3 and 4 please

Comment: You mean to say after limit ?

Comment: Line after `global $wpdb;`

Comment: Given notice : Notice: Undefined index: page

Comment: That is your problem. Custom rewrite regex not compatible with your urls. What urls are you feeding in?

Comment: Current my URL is - http://wwwtes.com/dev-s/spring/user-listing/2/
AND I want :http://wwwtes.com/dev-s/spring/user-listing?page=2 with working pagination

Comment: You will need to do some debugging in your `custom_rewrite_rule` - is it even being executed? I think not because it is not even setting the `page` get variable. Not familiar with Wordpress rewrite rules but can't see why you have in addition to your rule: `add_query_var` with `page`.